# cross reference to a table in rmarkdown with the correct table number in word document

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am trying to reference a table in a word document using `bookdown` package.

I wanted to add the reference id in the `fig.cap` parameter of the code chunk, but this is somehow not seen by the interpreter and I don't get the link to the reference.

As a workaround, I added my reference ID to the caption of the table, but here the full  id (`{#mysecondtable2}`) is written in the figure caption and this looks ugly.

Any idea on how to solve this? Maybe LUA filter to remove the ugly anchor from the table caption? I don't understand how to do this.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mario"
date: '2022-11-10'
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    toc: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

See Table \@ref(tab:myfirsttable).  Or click [Table \@ref(tab:mysecondtable)](#mysecondtable2). 

```{r myfirsttable, echo = FALSE}
knitr::kable(cars, caption = "First three rows of cars dataset")
```

See Table \@ref(tab:mysecondtable).

```{r mysecondtable, echo = FALSE, fig.cap='{#mysecondtable2}'}
knitr::kable(head(iris, 3), 
             caption='{#mysecondtable2} test')
```
````

EDIT:

Some strange behaviour shows, that `[Table \@ref(tab:mysecondtable)](#mysecondtable)` seems to work. But actually it only refers to the caption of the second table but ignores the 2 at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straight-forward solution is to wrap the table into an extra div, as one can then link to that div:

````
Or click [Table \@ref(tab:mysecondtable)](#mysecondtable-wrapper).

::: {#mysecondtable-wrapper}
```{r mysecondtable, echo = FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(iris, 3),
             caption='test')
```
:::
````

A slightly less crude way is to put a span into the caption:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris, 3),
             caption='[test]{#mysecondtable}')
```

The difference between the two is that the link will point at the whole table when using a div, and to the caption when using a span.

Comment: Hi @tarleb, thanks, this DIV solution works like a charm! The caption solution is not working in flextables caption. At least in my solution it always prints the complete `[test]{#mysecondtable}` and not only the `test` caption.

Comment: Hi @tarleb, is there a way to get a table numbered without a caption? So, If I remove the table caption, the `\@ref(tab:X)` returns `??`.

Comment: @drmariod Numbering happens in R Markdown, but I don't know any details. Sorry.